# How to make the tab sequence to work for an image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using images as buttons and then writing click events for it, but when I tried to give the tab sequence for it, it's not focusing the image. The following is the line of code that I'm using to add tab sequence:

```
$("#element").attr('tab-sequence', 21);
```

But it's not working.

Any other suggestion would help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#element").attr('tabindex', 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
$("#element").attr('tab-sequence', 21);
```

to

```
$("#element").attr('tabindex', 21);
```

Also, make sure that the id is unique for every element